# Хочу создать горизонтальный сайт, около 6-7 страниц, как расположить страницы горизонтально?

Tags: jquery, html, вёрстка, css

1 страница на дисплее, нажал кнопку выкатилась другая, такая же width 100%, height 100%. Подскажите как делается, подкиньте ссылку на урок. Смотрел, но там только примеры сайтов, а как делается, не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Подходов много например все страницы кроме главной position:absolute; left:100%; от body ну и к страницам применить transition. По клику на пункт меню возвращаешь нужную страницу - тоесть left:0; top:0; ну это так что первое в голову пришло. Но хочу предупредить 6-7 страниц будешь прятать - нагрузка будет не хилая - в этом случае поможет ajax - но это совсем другая история))

Answer (score 0):

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ может поможет.